# How to compile Arduino ESP8266/32 on CI/CD (CLI shell cmd) platform?

Tags: esp8266, esp32, command-line

Like make for not ESP Arduino target, is there a CLI command like **esptool.py** to upload in the hardware ?

I've seen [**makeEspArduino**](https://github.com/plerup/makeEspArduino) but seems to be not trivial ?

What about [**espressif ESP32** component](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/docs/esp-idf_component.md) ?

Is [**Visual Micro** Arduino CLI (Command Line Interface)](http://www.visualmicro.com/page/Visual-Micro-Command-Line-Interface.aspx) tool mature ?

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/arduino/arduino-builder/wiki/Doing-continuous-integration-with-arduino-builder

Comment: Thanx [Craig](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/337/craig). I'll have a deep look...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest answer: Use [PlatformIO](https://platformio.org/). (Yes this answer is technically an advertisement, but it *is* the correct solution here.).

*Why not the others?*

- `makeEspArduino` is dependent on GNU `make`, hard to make modification to, hard to get support for when something goes wrong
- Visual Micro Arduino is Visual Studio extension, thus native to Windows

*Why PlatformIO?*

On the other hand, PIO is just a framework written in python2, runs on Windows, Mac & Linux alike and supports tons of boards and frameworks. Not only is it OS-agnostic but it also IDE agnostic. It exports project files for Eclipse, Visual Studio Code, CLion, Visual Studio, Sublime, Atom and other IDEs. The Arduino IDE will always be only a (bad) syntax highlighter.

Support boards (479 of them) range from Arduino Unos to ESP8266/ESP32 over to STM32 and nRF boards. It's also possible to compile one firmware for different environments (board), so with a well-written firmware, PIO can generate firmwares for multiple boards and frameworks alike. Frameworks include Arduino cores, ESP-IDF, STM32HAL and more.

To create a new project, you'd do

```
user@somefolder/$ pio init --board=nodemcuv2 --ide=vscode
```

To compile from CLI, you just have to execute the `run` target:

```
user@somefolder/$ pio run
```

To upload you'd just

```
user@somefolder/$ pio run -t upload
```

With optional `--upload-port=/dev/ttyUSB0` or alike. Updating wirelessly over ArduinoOTA is also supported.

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIkGTwLOD7o

Documentation: http://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thanx a lot [Maximilian Gerhardt](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/30175/maximilian-gerhardt) for this complete answer